# Register a logger type with unique logger name

Tags: .net, logging, castle-windsor, structuremap

I have done this before with StructureMap and now I wish to do the same with Windsor Castle. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
Registry.For<ILogger>().Use(s => 
new Logger(s.ParentType ?? s.BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType));
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I am alone with this question. Nobody is ever moving from structuremap to windsor castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got some help from a team member instead that has been using Windsor Castle.

This is how it need to be written.

```
Component.For<ILogger>().UsingFactoryMethod((m, v, i) =>
                    new Logger(i.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Name)
                ).LifeStyle.Transient
```